# Get list of caches which lost partitions in Apache Ignite

Tags: c#, .net, docker, ignite, gridgain

I wanna use script to reset lost partitions `control.sh --cache reset_lost_partitions <cacheName1,cacheName2,...>`, but I don't know how to get the list of caches which I need to reset. Is there any way to get the list of caches by **bash**?

I tried to get the list using .NET app, but unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see them in the logs. The message should be similar to the following:

```
Detected lost partitions [grp=MY_CACHE, parts=[10, 219, 232, 471, 598, 682, 836, 869, 916, 1081, 1215, 1303, 1380, 1794, 1962, 1980
```

Where `MY_CACHE` is the cache name.

Alternatively, you can run the following command to check partition states:

```
control.sh --cache distribution null
```

To map cacheId to the cache name you can use the following [system view](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring-metrics/system-views#caches):

```
select * from SYS.CACHES
```